# Hibernate: Generating Reports (Stored pocedures)

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures

I am working on an application using Hibernate (JPA 2.0), Spring 3.0.5 and Oracle 11g.

I need to generate few reports (CSV's) based on a number of tables in the datasbase;

The sample report CSV looks like this:

```
From_Date    TO_Date     Group   Metric     Mon     Tue      Wed     Thu    Fri

10/01/2012   10/02/2012   HP     Average    29       74       400     99     14 
10/02/2012   10/03/2012   HP     Average    81       19       22      108    07
10/03/2012   10/04/2012   HP     Average    11       62       09      16     01

10/01/2012   10/02/2012   HP     Total      924      452      915     100    940 
10/02/2012   10/03/2012   HP     Total      185      925      266     108    857
10/03/2012   10/04/2012   HP     Total      173      201      907     675    169
```

My question is as this report will depend on many tables and different metrics (average, total, and percentages), what is the best way forward with the given technology stack?

I am currently not using any reporting api currently.

Is stored procedure the way to go???

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

There are two pieces of tech you'll need:

- Something to retrieve and calculate data
- Something to create a visualisation

(+ optionally some scheduling mechanism for auto-generating the reports at intervals)

**Data retrieval**

I'd strongly argue against using JPA and Java code to assemble your data, as this will be usually slow, unless there is only a small amount of data.

If you are using JPA in your app, I'd first try using JPA view objects + JPA tuning (via config file/annotations).

If that does not work out, fall back to native JDBC.

More on this topic in my blog: [JPA Query result as a POJO](http://www.istvandevai.com/2012/06/jpa-query-result-as-pojo.html)

If even JDBC is too slow, I'd only then consider stored procedures (which are harder to write, version, keep in sync with your app, etc.)

**Visualisation**

- CSV files you can create yourself in Java without much effort
- For a proper reporting library/toolkit, see [Pentaho reporting](http://reporting.pentaho.com/) or [Jasperreports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports/)
- For ad-hoc reporting (repoting without a predefined schema, aka. data analysis), I'd recomment [Pentaho business analytics](http://www.pentaho.com/explore/products/).

Pentaho BI server (or similar products) benefit you mostly if you can take advantage of the whole toolchain provided (ETL to load data, report designer tool, data analyzer, report scheduler, etc.). If you only have a few reports and these won't change anytime soon, then I'd stick with a Java solution.

Comment: Just read the blog post - with Hibernate you can easily tranform a List<Object[]> to a POJO using a result transformer - Transformer.ALIAS_TO_BEAN. For some reporting we use a SQLQuery and a bean that maps to the report columns.

Comment: The API is query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ReportData.class));

Comment: Actually, what I've tried back then was to call entityManager.createQuery(java.lang.String qlString, java.lang.Class<T> resultClass) with resultClass as my POJO and this one did not work. It's good to know that there is a solution in case someone uses the Hibernate API.

Answer (score 1):

For reporting, you can use [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports/) (PDF) or [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) (MS Documents, for example, MS Excel)

Regards.

Comment: I know about the API's. Can you please elaborate why should I be using these?